# UIImage conversion to/from NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

I'm storing an image in a database by storing its string representation, like so:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 0.7);
NSString *imageString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: imageData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This string is then stored in the database. Later on in my code, I need to pull it out of the database and display it. I attempt to retrieve it like this:

```
NSData *data = [[items[i] objectForKey:@"image"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
UIImage *newImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

where `items` is an array of data retrieved from the database. However, when I retrieve it, `newImage` is nil. My encoding method is the one I have seen most frequently on this site, but now I'm thinking that it must be the problem. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Why are you converting your `imageData` to `NSString`?

Comment: you need to store image in to blob format

Comment: Don't do this: `[[items[i] objectForKey:@"image"] ..`.  Break it down into individual statements so you can see what you have at each stage.

Comment: (As the first two comments suggest, as soon as you convert the data to NSString it's hopelessly garbled and unrecoverable.  If storing in a SQL DB it should be stored as a "blob".)

Comment: I'm using Azure Mobile Services and it doesn't allow you to store a blob - only a number, string, date, or boolean. I'm trying to find a workaround using what's available.

Comment: Well, in that case use Base64.

Comment: Use Azure Blob Storage. To reply to a specific user's comment, prefix their username with an @ sign. For example, to reply to me, you'd type "@duci9y <your comment>".

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a base 64 encoded string as the representation of your data. For example, as of iOS 7.0, you could get the string from the image data by calling:

```
// Convert to string
NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
// Convert string to image
NSData *dataFromString = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64String options:0];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:dataFromString];
```

Comment: If the resulting `newImage` is `nil`, how will changing it to base-64 encoding help?

Comment: If this data is being stored in a SQL database it should be stored as a blob.  Storing as a Base64 string is unnecessary work.

Comment: Using this still results in a nil image. As stated in a comment above, the database doesn't allow me to store a blob.

Comment: When you tested it, did you make sure to re-encode any existing data you have? ie, calling initWithBase64EncodedString: and using a string you previously encoded as UTF-8 won't work. Can you verify that the data isn't nil after initWithBase64EncodedString?